# Android studio missing ARM image for gingerbread and honeycomb?

Tags: android, api, android-ndk, google-api, android-virtual-device

I want to create a AVD to test my app which uses google APIs in gingerbread 2.3 and honeycomb 3.2,
SO posts said that basically 2 choices exist

x86 image ->faster
ARM v7->slower but most actual devices run it

and the the two images also come with a Google API version which can help test apps using G-Maps etc

I use a Intel 64 bit process with HMAX installed ,vt-x and working fine

For API 21(Lollipop) I created an AVD with googleAPIx86 and x86-system-image and its fine and fast
(cause it seems for the googleAPI image need the corresponding system image should be there,for API 21 I could get both images for x86)

For  API 19(Kitkat) also I icreated AVD with googleAPIx86 and x86-system-image and it works

For API 18(Jelly Bean ) the google-api is available only in the ARM version, so i cannot use the x86 system image even though it is faster , so i created AVD with google-api(ARM version) and corresponding ARM-system-image

For API 15(Icecream sandwich ) Also the same as API 18 ,Used ARM for both

The problem now is

For API 13(Honey Comb) and API10(GingerbBread) the Google-API is available only in the ARM Version but the system image is present only in the x86 version.

So is there anyway to run my app using google APIs in these two emeulators ?

(NOTE:AVD Shows error and  doesn't   if i use a googleAPI-arm with x86system-image)

See screenshot below:

API 10 and 13 have only x86system image but only google-api-ARM
[image]

Comment: oh!ok not many devices came with honeycomb or the ones which did were upgraded?,but still is there any solution here,cause eclipse is not officially supported starting from last month and i need to test API10(Gingerbread)

Comment: I really don't care for Eclipse not being supported. It **works** for me (with all the beautiful **plugins**!)... I really didn't dowload the 19+ APIs because of the AlarmManager issues... So, still **targetting API 18 (forever)**. The UI and styles I do my own. **No need to follow the fashions**.

Comment: Glad it works for you, but i am sort of making an app(plaaning stage actually) using some cloud services and google services and i love material design (i don't use custom UI),so i have to find some some otherway i guess

Comment: Eclipse has the **API Level 21 SDK**, too. So **you can** really do Material Design UIs...

Comment: @DerGolem: "What is worse is that Froyo is missing" -- no, it is not. For example, you can see it in the screenshot in the question. It may require you to check the "Obsolete" checkbox in your SDK Manager, though.

Answer (score 2):

> For API 13(Honey Comb) and API10(GingerbBread) the Google-API is available only in the ARM Version but the system image is present only in the x86 version.

ARM images exist for all Android versions. However, it was only starting with API Level 14 were they called out into a separate installable item in the SDK Manager. In prior API levels, the ARM image comes as part of the "SDK Platform" item.

Comment: No, not part of platform, etc.. i guess x86 came only from API 14...they see to have made a error in naming,....it showed only x86 images for <API14..however they are ARM images.....i just checked